# Apache2 cant find /index.php error 404

Tags: php, apache

So I've set up an apache2 webserver on linux. Made a .php file but when I try to access `http://myhost/index.php` it gives me the `404 Not Found` Error. When I try to acccess `http://myhost` it gives me the ubuntu default page even though there is no `index.html` to be found in my directory `/var/www/html`. I have edited the `dir.conf` so `index.php` is up front. PS: making a phpinfo.

Comment: The fact that `http://myhost` gives you the default apache page without having anything in `/var/www/html` may indicate that the default apache home directory is not that one.

Comment: @apokryfos That is not the case. /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Comment: @Sorenkai current config should be in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, remember to restart apache after changes

Comment: I will just rebuild the entire vps and begin from the grounds. see if that works

Comment: How will rebuilding your VPS solve your lack of Apache configuration knowledge?

Comment: Following a tutorial on DigitalOcean. maybe?

Answer (score 0):

To start, I would put a simple index.html with some kind of "hello world!" on your server, so when it does come up, it is a clear success.

#### Things to check

Try only the IP address of the server in the browser, this should give you either the index.php or index.html in the `/var/www/html`.  This helps narrow down where the path breaks down (gets rid of hostname issues).

If it is a virtual server on your computer, you may have to use the port forwarding values like 127.0.0.1:8080, if port forwarding was set up.

Check the file permissions on /var/www/html, you can use this .sh script (might need to replace root with a username with root privs, depending on your setup):

```
sudo find /var/www -exec chown root:www-data {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod -v 750 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod -v 640 {} \;
```

If you put up a firewall, you need to double check port 80 is open.

As a last ditch effort, you can run `netstat -ant` on your server and you should see:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Indicating that Apache is indeed listening on port 80.

Hopefully one of those things will help you figure it out, good luck!