# apache2 default home page not loading after serer migration

Tags: apache, apache2.2

Hi recently got my server migrated and its IP got changed.

When i try to open my IP in the browser, the Apache 2 default home page which should load up is not loading, not sure if its cause of IP chnage, which i highly doubt.

I am getting : 404 not found

> The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Tried all the possible searches and did R & D, but couldn't solve.

**Following steps checked:**

1) Apache 2 server running

2) mod_rewrite enabled

2) tail -f apache logs..no errors there

Below is my apache2.conf file

**etc\apache2\apache2.conf**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**My etc\apache2\sites-available\000-default.conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com
#ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
 #vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

What are the other possibilities that i need to check to solve this??

Comment: file permissions? See, for example, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000180/apache2-cant-find-index-php-error-404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000180/apache2-cant-find-index-php-error-404).

Comment: yes checked that too...gave all required permission to /var/www/html.  any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my 000-default was somehow deleted or or was not there in sites-enabled folder of apache...thanks.its working after enabling the same.

sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf

service apache2 reload